# Finished Mass Effect 1. Now how can I play the BDtS DLC?

Tags: mass-effect

The most recent Mass Effect saves I got are from within the Citadel (attacked @ end game). I'm losing 2 hours of gameplay if I load the last save where I was in control of the Normandy. You lose the Normandy once you land on Ilos.

So the question is... how the hell can I play the DLC and have it reflect in Mass Effect 2 without re-playing all the game ending?

If this is not possible, I think I will use the Mass Effect savegames website, although I would feel like I'm cheating. However, maybe this is the only way now that I finished the game already without playing the DLC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put: This is not possible.

Like I mentioned in your other question - once you're on Illos, there's no going back. If you'd like to carry over your results from Bring Down the Sky, you'll have to complete the mission before Illos.

Comment: I, of course, remember your answer ::- ). But I hoped that there is some sort of hidden command in the menus I did not notice. I am disappointed in the game's functionality concerning these matters. Once you finish it they should allow you to return to Normandy and the map. Oh well, that's that then. I'll have to re-play the ending. Truth be told, I liked the ending so I won't mind replaying it... after a few weeks ::- D. Thanks again Raven ::- ).

Comment: @Axonn Indeed - Bioware agrees - they added that "return to the Normandy after the last mission" to Mass Effect 2.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I didn't finish that one yet. Played about an hour. Now I'm gonna have to re-do that as well ::- D. But since it's a great game, I won't mind.